# How to store an array into a cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

How do you store a multi-array type of data into a cookie.

For example: `[[1, 'foo'], [2, 'bar'], [3, 'foobar']]`

I can get it to work with a single dimensional array as such:

```
cookies[:foobar] = { :value => cookies[:foobar] << ",1" }
```

and then do

```
cookies[:foobar].split(',').include?("1")
```

To verify that `1` exists inside the cookie. Not too sure how I can get around this with a multidimensional array

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Serialize array into json and store to cookies.

Look at two methods:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(object)
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(string)
```

Comment: Hmmmm, doesn't Rails cookies decode data already? Consider: `cookies[:test] = { :value => ActiveSupport::JSON.encode({ :color => ["red", "green", "yellow"] }), :expires => 24.hours.from_now }` returns `{"color"=>[red, "green", "yellow"]}`. I don't need to decode?

Comment: I think you always have to decode string data into array object.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably to use one of the serialisation methods rails/ruby provides such as YAML, marshalling or json.